# Strategy Pattern using Unity

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, unity-container, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to use the Strategy pattern using dependecy injection with Unity, and i have the following scenario:

```
public Interface IName
{
  string WhatIsYourName()
}

public class John : IName
{
   public string WhatIsYourName()
   {
     return "John";
   } 
}

public class Larry : IName
{
   public string WhatIsYourName()
   {
     return "Larry";
   } 
}

public Interface IPerson
{
   IntroduceYourself();
}

public class Men : IPerson
{
   private IName _name; 

   public Men(IName name)
   {
     _name = name;
   }

   public string IntroduceYourself()
   {
     return "My name is " + _name.WhatIsYourName();
   }
}
```

How can i set unity container to inject the correct name to the correct person?

Example:

```
IPerson_John = //code to container resolve
IPerson_John.IntroduceYouself(); // "My name is john"

IPerson_Larry = //code to container resolve
IPerson_Larry.IntroduceYouself(); // "My name is Larry"
```

Similar problem:
[Strategy Pattern and Dependency Injection using Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706056/strategy-pattern-and-dependency-injection-using-unity)
. Unfortunately, I cannot use this solution once i have to inject dependecy in the "constructor"

Comment: you could use generics i guess. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/d5x73970.aspx
This way you would end with IPerson_John = new Person<John>();
But that makes no use of Unity

Comment: I don't think that you should use DI for these classes. See this article for more details: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is *You cant*. 
Because:
What you are doing with Men class is you are making ***Poor Man's Dependency Injection***. You dont need to create poor man's dependency injection if you are using unity, this is why unity helps you as a framework. Suppose if you have more than one type as parameters when you make **constructor injection** like

```
public Men(IName name, IAnother another,IAnother2 another2)
  {
     _name = name;
     // too much stuff to do....
  }
```

What you could do? You really dont wanna deal with that, so thats why you can use Unity.

You have to register type and resolve them according to type name.

```
container.RegisterType<IName, Larry>("Larry");
container.RegisterType<IName, John>("John");
```

And then

```
IName IPerson_John=container.Resolve<IName>("John");
IPerson_John.IntroduceYouself(); // "My name is john"

IName IPerson_Larry= container.Resolve<IName>("Larry");
IPerson_Larry.IntroduceYouself(); // "My name is Larry"
```

You can check that [article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/25/DependencyInjectionInversionin.NET/)